# PictureBox that moves when it should not move

Tags: c#, winforms, events, mousemove, mousedown

I have a problem with a custom class that inherits from `PictureBox`. On the `OnMouseDown` event I center the location of my cursor, and on the `OnMouseMove` event I move the `pictureBox`.

The problem is that when I center the location of the cursor, it also moves the `pictureBox`.

I need first to locate the cursor on the center of the `pictureBox` and then move the `pictureBox` when I move the cursor.

I try to put a bool that controls the `Click` event, but it is doing all the same way.

Method that puts the `pictureBox` at a correct `Point`:

```
public void Colocar(Control control, Unidad unidad, Point p)
{
    unidad.Location = p;
    control.Controls.Add(unidad);
}
```

`OnMouseDown` event handler:

```
bool clickPerformed = false; 
bool clickMove = false; //Para saber si hay que moverlo
private Point MouseDownLocation;
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseDown(e);

    this.Cursor = new Cursor(Cursor.Current.Handle);
    Cursor.Position = new Point(this.Location.X + this.Size.Width / 2, this.Location.Y + this.Size.Height / 2);

    clickPerformed = true; 
    Control tempSender = this.Parent; 
    tempSender.Invalidate(); 
    MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
    clickMove = true;
}
```

`OnMouseUp` event handler:

```
protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    this.Parent.Invalidate();
    clickMove = false;
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

Method to draw a circle arround the `pictureBox`:

```
public void DrawCircle(Graphics g, Pen pen, float centerX, float centerY, float radius)
{
    g.DrawEllipse(pen, centerX - radius, centerY - radius, radius + radius, radius + radius);
}
```

`OnMouseMove` event handler:

```
protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnMouseMove(e);
    if (clickMove)
    {
        Left = e.X + Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        Top = e.Y + Top - MouseDownLocation.Y;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a thought but can't you make a `bool` set it `false` as a default and only move the picturebox if its true, then just set it to `true` AFTER you center the mouse. Tell me if it works for you, I'll make it into an answer

Comment: I know you already have 1 so maybe keep that false untill you centered the mouse?

Comment: I set the bool 'clickMove' true after the cursor's location changes, but It still moves the pictureBox when I click on it. Do you think I have the bool wrong?

Comment: Your code worked once I commented out the Cursor.Position code.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't take the cursor where I wanted to take. I mean, I need to put the cursor on the centre of the pictureBox after I click the pictureBox and then move that pictureBox. But, when I click on the pictureBox, it moves the cursor and it also moves the pictureBox, so it never goes to the centre of the pictureBox because the new location of the cursor moves also the pictureBox. I don't know if you understand me. (Sorry for the late response)

Comment: It's not clear why you want to move the cursor.  No user enjoys when that happens.

Comment: I need it. Is one requirement.